# If cell A1 is greater than B1, cut and paste row to first empty row

Tags: excel, vba

If cell in column I1-I14 is greater than cell in column J1-J14, I want to cut the entire row and paste values to the first empty row. (From row 16 and down.)

If cell i is greater than cell j, cut row and paste values to first empty row (row 16 in this example)
[image]

This code just pastes in the first row:

```vb
Sub Knapp6_Klicka()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    j = 1
    For i = 3 To 500
        If Cells(i, 9).Value > Cells(i, 10).Value Then
            Cells(i, 12).EntireRow.Cut Sheets("Blad1").Range("A" & j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

I tried to combine the paste with two different solutions.

One like this, where I recorded a macro and went to the last cell, then up to the first empty cell:

```vb
Range("A1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

And one solution that I found on an Excel community:

```vb
Sub compareresult()
    
    Dim row1 As Integer
    Dim row2 As Integer
    
    row2 = 1
    For row1 = 8 To 500
        If sheet1.Cells(row1, 11).value > sheet1.Cells(row1, 9).value Then
            sheet1.Cells(row1, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(11).Cells(row2, 1)
            row2 = row2 + 1
        End If
    Next row1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get the rows your actually wanting to do it on. You say to check 1-14 then cut to 16 onwards but your codes start from 3 or 8 and go to 500.
Also your first attempt would paste to row 1 because you set `j = 1`. You need to find the last row which I can help with but what are your actual ranges?

Comment: You would need to count the rows in column I try the following.
`Range("A" & cells(rows.count,"I").end(xlup).row + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this.

It's based on the range you gave. Skipped over row 1 since you have headers in it.

```
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Blad1") 'Your sheet name
lRow = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finding the last row
If lRow < 16 Then lRow = 16 'The starting row you want to cut to

For i = 2 To 14 'Your range of rows to check
    If ws.Range("I" & i) > ws.Range("J" & i) Then
        ws.Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Cut ws.Range("A" & lRow) 'Cutting the whole row so you use column A to cut to
        lRow = lRow + 1 'Move down 1 row for where to cut to
    End If
Next i
```

Edit:

Because you only want the values to copy accross we can't use `Cut` and `PasteSpecial xlValues` so instead we will duplicate the value of the entire row to the new location, then clear the row (filling in for the cutting part). If clear is too much we can just `ClearContents` to remove the values in the cells instead of the formatting if that happens. Make sure to always save before running VBA code for the first time.

```
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Blad1") 'Your sheet name
lRow = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finding the last row
If lRow < 16 Then lRow = 16 'The starting row you want to cut to

For i = 2 To 14 'Your range of rows to check
    If ws.Range("I" & i) > ws.Range("J" & i) Then
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).EntireRow.Value = ws.Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Value 'Copying the values over
        ws.Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Clear 'Clear the row
        lRow = lRow + 1 'Move down 1 row for where to cut to
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Really appreciate it! 
The only thing I need now is to paste special.. 
I completely forgot to explain that part in my post. What I meant by "post value" was to paste special, and just paste the value and not forumlas.

But now I saw that I had been extremely vague in my formulation!
Do you know how to solve that part also?

Comment: Yep sure I will quickly change to that. Just to be clear you are only wanting to cut and not delete the row right? Because you will be left with blank rows. Of course you may be wanting that for your purposes but just checking.

Comment: Great :)) Yes i just want to cut the rows and leave them empty. I will later try to create a button to sort the rows, or try to figure out a way to make it sort the rows with the same button as for the cut and paste. To stack the filled rows first with no empty rows between. But that's a project for later :)

Comment: You can still do it in the same sub, just do it after the loop has finished. If you are going to delete rows in a loop (just as an FYI) you need to do it backwards. ie instead of `For i = 1 To 10` you do `For i = 10 To 1 Step -1`. This is because when you delete a row, the rows below shift up 1 so in a normal loop you will end up skipping the row that was below it because it's now in the same place as the row you just deleted.

Answer (score 2):

> If cell in column I1-I14 is greater than cell in column J1-J14, i want to cut entire row and paste values to the first empty row. (From row 16 and down)

Here is a method which doesn't cut and paste in a loop. Since you are not deleting the row or "cutting and inserting" the row, here is a simple approach. The below code follows a basic logic

**Logic**

1. Loop and identify the range.
2. If found, then copy the range in 1 go.
3. Finally clear the range which was copied (if copied).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Loop and identify the range
        For i = 2 To 14
            If .Range("I" & i).Value2 > .Range("J" & i).Value2 Then
                If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToCopy = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        '~~> If found then copy and clear
        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
            rngToCopy.Copy .Rows(16)
            rngToCopy.Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

To incorporate new edits

> Works perfectly! Thanks! :) I failed to fully describe my problem.. What i also need is to paste it as special (only paste the value and not the formulas). Do you got any quick solution for that? – Johl 5 hours ago

Replace

```
rngToCopy.Copy .Rows(16)
```

to

```
rngToCopy.Copy
DoEvents
.Rows(16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! :)
I failed to fully describe my problem.. What i also need is to paste it as special (only paste the value and not the formulas). Do you got any quick solution for that?

Comment: Yup. I have updated the post. You may have to refresh the page to see the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doomed to failure because you do not take into consideration that you are cutting the found row.  Think about what that means.  Your row with the In,Out is row 15 and you wish to paste to row 16.  If you cut  row 5 (for example) then rows 15 and 16 will become rows  14 and 15.  It also means that your next row (which you think will be row 6) will actually be what was row 7 before the cut.

Comment: `If you cut row 5 (for example) then rows 15 and 16 will become rows 14 and 15.` No that is not true. :) When you cut and paste, it doesn't delete the row till the time you cut and insert the row at a new destination. See the first two lines of my post.

Comment: After the cut and paste operation if the target row for paste is row 16?

Comment: Till the time you do not do an insert copied row in 16, the rows will not shift. Try it :)

Comment: You are missing the point.  After the first cut and paste things go wrong.

Comment: @freeflow It's cutting and pasting, which does not delete nor insert rows therefore the row numbers don't change.

Comment: @Simon  I haven't seen such a mistaken comment for a long time. You have a control variable i which is being used to index rows.   Lets say the I is 10 and thus indexing row 10.  Row 10  is cut and pasted to row 10+n.  That means that what was row 11 is now row 10.  VBA does not know you are using i to index rows, so it does not know that row 11 has become row 10.  at the Next statement i is incremented to 11.  When used as an index for rows i is now pointing to what used to be row 12.  Row 11, which is now row 10 is skipped over.  I hope this more clearly explains the problem.

Comment: @freeflow As Siddharth said. Why don't you try it. When you cut and paste it only deletes the cut row if you insert. If you use `.cut` in VBA then use the destination option it doesn't delete the row.